# "Uniqueness" of the Yamaguchi submersions of Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

The Yamaguchi submersion theorem says the following. Let $\{M_i\}$ be a sequence of $n$-dimensional smooth connected closed Riemannian manifolds of diameter at most $D$ and sectional curvature at least $\kappa$ which converges in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense to a smooth closed Riemannian manifold $N$. Then there exist sequence of positive numbers $\varepsilon_i\to 0$ and smooth submersions $f_i\colon M_i\to N$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
(1-\varepsilon_i)|\xi|<df_i(\xi)<(1+\varepsilon_i)|\xi|
\end{eqnarray}
for any tangent to $M_i$ vector $\xi$ orthogonal to the fiber of $f_i$, and 
$$|dist(f_i(x),f_i(x'))-dist(x,x')|<\varepsilon_i$$
for any $x,x'\in M_i$.

Of course the maps $f_i$ are highly non-unique. **I am wondering to what extend these maps $f_i$ are non-unique.** More precisely is the following statement true?

Let $f_i,f_i'\colon M_i\to N$ be the Yamaguchi submersions as above. Then after a choice of subsequence, there exists an (independent of $i$) isometry $I\colon N\tilde\to N$ and homeomorphisms $\phi_i\colon  N\tilde\to N$, $\psi_i\colon M_i\to M_i$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_i\circ I\circ f_i=f_i'\circ \psi_i,\\
\sup_{y\in N}dist(y,\phi_i(y))<\varepsilon_i.
\end{eqnarray}

If this statement is not correct or unknown to be true, I would appreciate to learn what is known in this direction. A reference would be helpful.